# flutter create fails "no pubspec.yaml found"

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create a new project and flutter immediately fails with 'no pubspec.yaml' found. And indeed, there is none.

It only created an android directory, an android\gradle and am android\gradle\wrapper directory, not a single file in th root directory.

Here is the output of the create command:

```
$ flutter create -v pics
[  +34 ms] executing: [c:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +153 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +2 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [c:\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +80 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[        ] executing: [c:\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[ +107 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[        ] executing: [c:\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +76 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 5391447fae6209bb21a89e6a5a6583cac1af9b4b
[        ] executing: [c:\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[ +120 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 6 weeks ago
[        ] executing: [c:\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[ +139 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.0.0-0-g5391447fa
[ +386 ms] Creating project pics...
[  +45 ms] "flutter create" took 243ms.
d:\src\flutterapps\pics: no pubspec.yaml found

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:26:3)
#1      pubGet (package:flutter_tools/src/dart/pub.dart:87:7)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      CreateCommand._generateApp (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:478:13)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      CreateCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/create.dart:319:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:401:18)
#5      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:77:64)
#6      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1132:38)
#7      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
#8      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:129:18)
#9      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:642:45)
#10     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:671:32)
#11     Future._complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:476:7)
#12     _SyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:51:12)
#13     _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/runtime/libasync_patch.dart:33:20)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
#16     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
#17     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
#18     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
#19     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:115:13)
#20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:172:5)
```

The flutter doctor comand produces following output:

```
$ flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18309.1000], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.2)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.30.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Please advise

Comment: Try `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor` `flutter create pics`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused a corrupted flutter instalation, not detected by flutter doctor. As described in [Flutter installation corrupted](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted) I ran following commands:

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
flutter doctor
```

And now my 'flutter create pics' works out fine

Comment: I tried the same commands but it still gives the same error. here is the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63206603/unable-to-create-new-flutter-project-on-android-studio-getting-error-could-no