# unable to create new flutter project on android studio getting error => Could not find a file named “pubspec.yaml” at project location drive

Tags: windows, android-studio, flutter

I installed flutter by following flutter documentation.
This is the error I'm getting=> Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "E:". pub get failed (66; Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "E:".
when I checked my project directory(E:\Fapplication) there was an empty folder with the project name(flutter_appp) but the android studio also created the same folder(flutter_appp) directly in the project location's drive(E:) with all contents of the project.
flutter doctor -v checked and environment variable is also set and I also tried to create the project on command prompt but it resulted in a similar error. I must be doing a little mistake which I can't find, please help.
[[image: ][1]]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have a corrupted install of Flutter. I would suggest you go to this Github [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted) and follow the commands shown by Flutter, but make sure that you run it in your Flutter install directory since it already caused some problems for someone in [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62175) who didn't run it in the correct directory. This is one of my first contributions, so let me know if it fixes your issue. Thanks

Comment: I searched more places and all of the similar problems were fixed with the Github commands. The only thing I would suggest is to delete the Flutter install directory and reinstall Flutter, maybe follow a YT video.

Comment: @akshay ashok Just now I found a GitHub issue post(https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2443) with the same issue, and they were able to fix it by reinstalling Flutter from the Github repository instead of installing it through the ".zip" file. I don't know what the difference between them is, but it might fix your issue too.

Comment: I reinstalled it for 6-7 times already. Tried every type of installation watching YT videos. Still, it gives the same error. I think the problem is related to the path of pubspec.yaml file. Anyways thanks for your efforts!!

Comment: actually I already tried reinstalling it using Github repository!

Comment: The only thing I can suggest now is to open a Github issue in the Flutter repository since non of the materials on the web helped fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me several times:

What's ultimately solved things for me (OS X) is deleting pub's cache:

sudo rm -Rf /Users//.pub-cache

Also, delete the packages directory in your project's root:

sudo rm -Rf packages

Then pub gets again in your project(s), but make sure that you are not operating as root (a whoami will tell you, and an exit will get you out of there).

Comment: in which directory should I run this command (sudo rm -Rf /Users//.pub-cache)? and I don't have a project root directory because I'm unable to create the project.